# Share WordPress login info with other PHP app

Tags: login, session

A customer asked for this feature:

- website with WordPress
- website with PHP app where is a login form
  Request is:
  "when i login info WordPress I've to be able to share login data with the PHP app so the login on PHP website is automatic"
  I've to share a session cookie?

I've tried to search about it but I'm new to this feature and I don't know from where and how i can start to find infos.
Thankyou very much

Comment: If you are under same domain, you can read the WordPress auth cookie, or even load WordPress enviroment and use WordPress functions like `is_user_logged_in()`. If you are in different domains, there are several options, like oAuth, web token authentication, etc. Unfortunately, not sure how to answer your question in a more specific way.

Comment: For an application I'm doing the opposite once logged in the application the user is automatically logged in Wordpress with `wp_set_auth_cookie` function